# Why does the Normalization cause different output value?

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining

Why does the Normalization cause different output value?

My program : https://i.stack.imgur.com/VXxg3.png

```
After Normalization, 4.0 becomes 0.8
After Normalization, another 4.0 becomes 1.00

After Normalization, 0.0 has become 0.00
After Normalization, another 0.0 becomes 0.000000
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Answer (score 1):

As evident from your image, in mvr1 the precision of 0.75 is more than that of 0.0; hence the precision of the latter is changed to match the precision of all values.